# Which is the best payment gateway to integrate with asp.net?

Tags: payment-gateway

I know this question may be repeat , but i didn't get any of previous ones.

which is the best and safe gateway to implement a shopping cart application in asp.net ? how we can integrate it with application ? which is best way to implement this. I want to develop this application in asp.net and c# . please guide me. this topic is new for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no best payment gateway. They all have benefits and flaws and MOST have API's that you can use to integrate

try [Google Checkout](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_NET.html)

[Paypal](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks)

[SagePay](http://www.sagepay.com/products_services/sage_pay_go/integration/compare)

read about these integrations and see what is right for you and what will be best for you to use

Comment: You can also figure out if there is some local player who is providing transaction in native currency.

Comment: Ok, let say I  selects the Paypal as option, then what should the basic requirements to integrate it with asp.net + c# ?

Comment: im sorry i dont know what you mean by basic requirements - you mean how would you get started - do you want some sample code?